# Create grid-style layout for Options Menu in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-menu

I've just met some troubles in Android 4.0.3 with menu because it displays menu item in a list. But I can't a way to set it displaying in a grid-like layout.
Appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, I found the main reason why you couldn't display option menu as grid-style in Android 4.0.3.
Because you used **@android:style/Theme.Holo** for your application.
Menu of Theme.Holo was set for displaying in list-style.

The solutions are:

1, Try to use another theme such as **@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar** instead of **@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar**

2, Or if you still want to use Theme.Holo, so try to create a style for menu in  **values/style.xml**. References: see styles in Android Framework. (Sr, I don't have Android framework here, so I can't show you what to do exactly now)

Hope this help!